# aws cp files with date as "wildcard parameter"

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I am attempting to copy a specific file from an s3 bucket, where the file that I am looking for, contains todays date as part of the name, like:

"myfile-2018-05-04.csv"

I do not have listing permissions to that bucket, so I was wondering if there is a way to pass the date as parameter, and use that in my command. Something like:

```
aws cp s3://someoneElsesBucket/ G:\Import\ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "[todaysdate].csv"
```

There are - in the same bucket - files named like "myfile-full-2018-05-04.csv", that are created on a weekly basis, so to look for the newest file would give me the wrong file at least once a week.

Is it possible to search by such a parameter? Or is there another way I can find the correct file to download?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `ListObjects` permission on the bucket, then wildcard requests will fail. This is because there is no underlying wildcard call in Amazon S3. Instead, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) needs to list the files in the bucket and then make requests to obtain the specific files.

If you know the exact name of the file you wish to copy, you could issue the `aws s3 cp myfile-2018-05-04.csv .` command, even without `ListOjbects` permission.